# How to align label next to Captcha textbox

Tags: c#, razor

I want to display text/label "Case sensitive" right next to my Captcha textbox. 
Like this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duXjM.png)

Currently, it is displaying below the textbox. How to align text next to textbox?

Here is my code :

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
     @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" }) (Case sensitive)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just define it as text and add " " like so:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
 @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", "", new { @class = "form-control" }) <text>(Case Sensitive)</text>
</div>
```

This should work fine. Alternatively you can add a placeholder:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
     @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", "", new { @class = "form-control" }, new { placeholder = "Case Sensitive"})
</div>
```